# Intellisense with Resharper in break mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, intellisense, code-completion

I'm using the latest version of Resharper (5.1.3) with the intellisense (Code completion and parameter info). I'm programming in c#. The intellisense of Resharper is very nice and work perfectly when the application is not running but when I run my WinForms project and hit Ctrl+Break (Break all and using edit and continue) to modify some code without stoping the application, the intellisense of Resharper stop working. In this case, I must stop the application, make changes and restart. Ok, I'm able to modify the code while the application is running but without intellisense.

Is this a limitation of Resharper or I have missed to activate or desactivate an option?

Just for the information, I have already desactivate the Visual Studio intellisense and parameter info (`Tools>Options>Text Editor>C#>General>Statement completion`). I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 with WinForms project like I said previously.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still works if you press **ctrl+space** yourself. I suppose it's by design, so nothing we can do about that. It still gives the info when you explicitly ask for it by pressing **ctrl+space** or whatever your keyboard shortcut is, so it's not that bad.